# Store Yes, No, 'N/A' in column

Tags: sql-server

I am storing form values in a SQL Server table. A drop down field on the form has options Yes/NO/'N/A'. SQL Server's `bit` data type doesn't work with this field. Is there a way that I can store the user selections of Yes/NO/'N/A' in my table?

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) shows, the `BIT` type can actually take on *three* values:

> An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.

So, you could use 0 for no, 1 for yes, and `NULL` could be allowed to represent `N/A`.

Comment: Thanks Tim for replying. I am new to SQl server. Would you pleas give an example of how can I make null represent N/A in my table definition?

Comment: Just declare the column as `BIT` and leave it as nullable (which should be the default behavior anyway).  Other than this, you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: I can't help you with your view technology, but I can only say that it needs to handle 0, 1, and `NULL` each in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

A bit datatype is an integer data type which can store either a 0 or 1 or null value. - It is used to store Boolean information like 1 or 0 (true or false).

Example to store data bit data type value:

```
   /* Creating table to store value for bit datatype*/
Create Table Selection_Store
(
    ColumnA     bit,
    ColumnA_value varchar(4)
)

---First way to provide value with true or false in bit datatype column which will store as 1 and 0 respectively

insert into Selection_Store (ColumnA , ColumnA_value)
values ( 'True'  , 'Yes') 
insert into Selection_Store (ColumnA , ColumnA_value)
values ( 'False'  , 'NO') 
insert into Selection_Store (ColumnA , ColumnA_value)
values ( null  , 'N/A')  

--Another way of declaring values as 1 and 0 instead boolean expression "True" or "False"
insert into Selection_Store (ColumnA , ColumnA_value)
values ( 1  , 'Yes') 
insert into Selection_Store (ColumnA , ColumnA_value)
values ( 0  , 'NO') 
insert into Selection_Store (ColumnA , ColumnA_value)
values ( null  , 'N/A') 

Output:
```

[image]